# Why did the captains and their crew from lots of other hovercrafts disregard Neo's supernatural ability in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

Why did the captains and their crew from lots of other hovercrafts disregard Neo's supernatural ability in the Matrix?

I think they must have noticed what Neo did in the Matrix. They didn't seem impressed with that. Meanwhile, they didn't even try to make use of it and scolded Morpheus' blind faith.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## They felt the battle should be fought in the "real world".

While the other captains might acknowledge — and may even be impressed by — Neo's feats in the Matrix, they would likely feel that the battle against the machines would be most successful in the "real world".

At least initially, there would be no reason for them to believe that Neo defeating agents in the Matrix would have any measurable benefit towards the security of Zion.

I believe this is best expressed by Commander Lock during his conversation with Morpheus in *Reloaded*:

> **MORPHEUS:** Commander, we need a presence inside the Matrix to await contact from the Oracle.
>
> **LOCK:** I don't want to hear that shit! I don't care about Oracles or prophecies or Messiahs. I care about one thing: stopping that army from destroying this city, and to do that I need soldiers to obey my orders.

Comment: To expand on this: many captains might feel that the only purpose of Matrix activity is liberating people from the Matrix, and while that's an excellent long-term goal, it's all for nothing if Zion is destroyed. Therefore, if Zion is under threat, they need to stop wasting resources on Matrix operations until Zion is safe.

From their perspective, running around in the Matrix has never disrupted real-world machine activities before, and it's ridiculous to think that that will change just because Neo figured out how to fly.

Comment: When you write the "real world" in quotation marks it makes me feel uneasy.

Comment: @joeytwiddle : *Well*, there is that theory that the "real world" in the Matrix is not actually the real world, but rather another level of Matrix ("yellow code" Matrix as opposed to "green code" Matrix, referring to the yellow aura that Neo sees around everything in *Revolutions*...)

Comment: @Praxis The "Matrix within Matrix" theory has been [debunked](http://www.matrixresolutions.com/index.html?page=debunked_matrix_within_matrix) many times, and even the writers weighed in on it to say that was not their intention, and it was just a misinterpretation by the fans.

Comment: @Chahk : Sure.  I was just pointing it out.  :-)